# Regex to only match a string that does not end with ")"

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.5

I have a plist file that has nested properties. I need to get the text immediately after the open "(", this is the "Name". I can do this fine, However, because there are nested properties,  when my C# logic iterates over the lines in the plist, the name gets overwritten by the next property. Is there a way to only match an exact pattern; specifically do not match any part of a string ends with a ")"

```
 : (MyNameHere                //Match
           : (propertyone)    // do not match, because it ends with ")"
```

here is the Regex I am using to match the name.

```
:\s\(([a-z,A-Z,0-9,-_]+)
```

I am using C#.net 4.5

Thanks

Comment: Could do do this with a read line loop and checking if line EndsWith(")") instead of a regex?

Comment: Can you provide a better example, one where the desired fields are not captured? Please specify what exactly should be captured and what shouldn't in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a positive lookahead assertion at the last if you don't want any other space character following `[\w-]+` . `(?=\s|$)` positive lookahead  which asserts that the match must be followed by a space character or end of the line anchor.

```
@":\s\(([\w-]+)(?=\s|$)"
```

Use `\s` if necessary or otherwise `@":\s\(([\w-]+)$` would be enough.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mF2vY7/2)

Comment: thanks Avinash, can you explain why the positive look ahead is looking for a space"\s"? I tried something similar, but i was looking for the ")". yours worked, and obviously mine didnt. just wondering why..

Comment: @user2219930 you're trying to match an exact word. Instead of adding a negative lookahead(_not ending with `)`_), a positive lookahead which checks for the following char must be `\s` or `$` will do the job you expected.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you are exactly trying to do but I suspect that balancing groups will interest you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you want to match a line that doesn't end with and not contain a closing parenthesis, you can use this pattern:

```
(?>[^\n)]*)(?!\))
```

details:

```
(?>...) # is an atomic group that prevents the regex engine to backtrack
(?!\))  # is a negative lookahead (not followed by ...) to check there
        # is not parenthesis after
```

The important thing is that `*` (as all other quantifiers) is greedy by default.

[About atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)

If you want to allow lines that can contain a closing parenthesis but can't end with a closing parenthesis:

```
(?m)^.*(?<!\))$
```